# Remove element from python list by identity rather than equality

Tags: python, list, reference

I am defining a Python object and I want it to have a method that I can invoke to move it around between various lists it might appear in. I wrote the following implementation:

```
def transfer(self, source, destination):
   source.remove(self)
   destination.append(self)
```

However, I soon discovered that the Python implementation of `list.remove` works by equality rather than identity; that is, if there is another element earlier in `source` which evaluates as equal to `self`, that one gets removed instead.

How can I implement this so I get the behavior I intend — that only the exact element referenced is removed from `source` and not any old element that is equal to it in value? Or, more likely, what is an alternative approach to implementing my `transfer` method?

Comment: Unless the `__eq__` method of the class has been overridden, the default comparison uses identity. How `list.remove` compares the values depends upon how `__eq__` is implemented.

Comment: @thecommexokid found one small bug in my code and added tests, check out the solution, please.

Comment: @thecommexokid hello did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `is` operator to the operation, it checks identity, that the object is same object, rather than equiliyty:

Code can look th efollowing way:

```
def transfer(self, source, destination):
    for i in range(len(source)):   # check all elements of the list
        # check if element is self ("is" checks not equality but identity)
        # "==" checks identity
        if source[i] is self:  
            element = source.pop(i)  # remove element by index to be sure that it is what we need
            break
    destination.append(element)
```

Some tests:

```
def transfer(x, source, destination):
    for i in range(len(source)):   # check all elements of the list
        # check if element is self ("is" checks not equality but identity)
        # "==" checks identity
        print(source[i])  # will print 4 times to prove that 4th element was taken
        if source[i] is x:

            element = source.pop(i)  # remove element by index to be sure that it is what we need
            break
    destination.append(element)


class Test:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.x == other.x:
            return True
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Test({})".format(self.x)

x, y, z, a = Test(1), Test(2), Test(3), Test(3)

list_1 = [x, y, z, a]
list_2 = []

transfer(a, list_1, list_2)
print(list_1)
print(list_2)
```

Let me know if it helped, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: This does everything I asked for, and by doing so, brought into clarity for me why what I asked for is not actually what I want.